# Update IP Geolocation for new public IPs

Tags: ipv4

We have been recently assigned new public IPs by ARIN but we have been having trouble with IP Geolocation. Some services block our IPs saying they are outside the US, others locate us in the geographic center of the US, not anywhere near where we are.

Our WhoIS records for our IPs and AS number all have our correct address and the location for our BGP peers is correct, so it would seem all the necessary information is available. Is there anything that can be done to update the various 3rd party IP Geolocation databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately as you encounter situations where geolocation is incorrect you have to track down the geolocation provider and ask them to update their database. Some provide web forms for this purpose.

- MaxMind: https://www.maxmind.com/en/correction
- Google: https://support.google.com/websearch/contact/ip